# GsonRequest class is a List

Tags: java, android, gson

I am currently making a GsonRequest as follows:

```
 final GsonRequest gsonRequest = 
   new GsonRequest(url, People.class, null, new Response.Listener<People>() { ... }
```

But my People class has only one member object: List of Person(s).

```
 public class People {
    private List<Person> people;
 }
```

I did it like because the argument for the GsonRequest called for a class (i.e., People.class). To me it seems strange and silly to make a class that only has one member object which is just a list of another objects. But the request I am making will return multiple Person(s). So, is there a better way? Can I pass a List of objects instead of a made up class like I did? My way is working, but I can't help but think there is a better way???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define it like this:

```
public class People extends List<Person> {
}
```

And that will work, at least you aren't defining a one-member class (you also need to make API change to match).

If you want to avoid the class completely, you can also use `TypeToken<E>`:

```
new TypeToken<List<Person>>(){}.getType()
```

However your GsonRequest class must be able to accept a Type instead of a class parameter.